# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm run server

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I am following a react and redux course and I want to run the server.

But when I do npm run server , it throw me this:

```
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! flashcard-app@1.0.0 server: `cd public; live-server --port=1234 --
entry-file=index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the flashcard-app@1.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Robbie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-
13T18_35_14_604Z-debug.log
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Start reading this [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay extra attention to MCVE part.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` in your terminal before running `npm run server`?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have an older version of either node js or npm. Check node **first** and update it, if necessary. Then, make sure that your npm is modern; node js will *automatically* include an older version of npm and delete your current one.